# C++ Initialized Variable Keeps Printing out as Zero Even though Function is Passed

Tags: c++, arrays, function, object, parameter-passing

I passed a function to calculate the sum of all the numbers in an array but it outputs as 0 which is what I initialized it to. The function is in a separate file from the actual program (I also created a class called Stats). When I display the total sum in the function, it shows the correct number. It's only when I initialize it to 0 is where it goes wrong. How can I make it where when I pass the function, the total actually updates to the correct amount and not zero.

```
const int num = 12;
class Stats
{
private:
    double stats[num];
    double total = 0;
public:
    void setValue(double stats[num], int);
    double calcTotal(double stats[num], double);

};

double Stats::calcTotal(double stats[num], double total)
{
    total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        total += stats[i];
    }
    cout << total;
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    double rainFall[num];
    double total = 0;

    Stats rainStats;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << "What was the rain fall for month #" << i + 1 << " ?" << endl;
        cin >> rainFall[i];
        rainStats.setValue(rainFall, num);
    }

    rainStats.calcTotal(rainFall, total);
    cout << total;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints out 0 in `int main()` but in `calcTotal`, it is the correct amount.

Comment: There's many part of the shown code that doesn't make sense or isn't needed. But the problem is that `calcTotal` *returns* the `total` but you just throw away (ignore) the returned result.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you tell me what doesn't make sense and what's unnecessary

Comment: Doesn't make sense: Passing `total` as an argument to `calcTotal`, instead of defining it as a local variable. Unnecessary: The whole class, really. `calcTotal` could be a non-member function and the class isn't needed at all. Just to mention two things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on [@Someprogrammerdude's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869727/c-initialized-variable-keeps-printing-out-as-zero-even-though-function-is-pass#comment121713085_68869727). You have to reassign the value of `total` to the value returned from `calcTotal()`, like this:

```cpp
total = rainStats.calcTotal(rainFall, total);
```

Comment: my brain really isnt working today LOL wow.

Comment: Haha we all have those days.

Comment: also you should not have `total` as an input parameter, because the function does not use the old value

Answer (score 1):

`total` is passed by-value, so it's just a copy of the argument, and any modification on it inside `calcTotal()` has nothing to do with the original argument passed-in (i.e. `total` in `main()`).

You can change to pass-by-reference (then don't need the return value).

```
void calcTotal(double stats[num], double&);
```

Or use the return value instead in `main()`.

```
total = rainStats.calcTotal(rainFall, total);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is doing so because you haven't given any value to num my friend

Answer (score 0):

Your function signature is confusing (although syntactically correct):

```
double Stats::calcTotal(double stats[num], double total)
```

It implies that the function would receive an array of `num` elements, and you are using that `num`  in a loop as a limit.

In fact, the global variable `const int num = 12;` is used as a loop limit, and your declaration is the same as

```
double Stats::calcTotal(double stats[], double total)
```

or

```
double Stats::calcTotal(double* stats, double total)
```

This is known as an "array to pointer decay"